# Chrome showing "NOT SECURE" with SSL installed

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get the "NOT SECURE" warning to go away on a site I am building for a friend (a1airsocal.com) and I have installed the SSL cert on the server and changed the wp directory to https, but it is still showing "NOT SECURE" next to the URL. When I view the site info though it says my certificate is installed and valid. I set it up exactly how I did a site for my brother (allhailbrand.com) with a different key of course, but the same process and that site works as intended.

I'm trying to understand why this is happening and have looked at the links on my page because I read that if image paths or links start with HTTP then it could still show the warning, but I don't think any of them are. The only other thing I can think is maybe its a problem with Wordpress, but alhailbrand.com is a WordPress site as well and even using the same theme. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm not the only one dealing with something like this what with all the new SSL rules.

Comment: `a1airsocal.com` is shown as secure, when I open it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @MarioWerner You are seeing the green lock next to the URL? Maybe it is my cache, but I thought I have cleared it.

Comment: Working fine for me. Green padlock is there on all pages.

Comment: I guess it just hadnt propogated yet? I waited more than 24 hrs though. Next time I will give it 3 days. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's good that you are sure about not any image is on http. Yet you are facing problem of non secure warning in the browser so you should try some methods listed below to check your website for http path (if any):

1. Look for the unsecured contents
2. With plugin find out unsecured (non-https) content
3. Use trusted [third third-party website](https://www.whynopadlock.com/) for searching out the mixed stuffs

Checkout resource based on above three points in detail to solve [mixed content warning](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-fix-mixed-content-warning-other-ssl-settings-in-wordpress).

Comment: Marked as correct answer because this would be the best trouble shooting method, though I did try all of this previously, but I guess I just had to wait for it to propogate. It had been over 24hrs, but I guess it can take longer than that.

Comment: Excellent! I was having this issue today and this appears to be the solution from looking at the certificate information and using "Why No Padlock". Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may have mix matched content that used by images. For Example some of images, Js and CSS files using http version of website that's why it shows insecure.

One more reason, if you have shared SSL then probably you will not get fully secured browser protection for your domain.

I hope it will be helpful for you!